# Using Django with or without Apache - development server

Tags: python, django, development-environment

I'm busy setting up Django on Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to know if there is/are any benefit/s to setting up the development environment with Apache and mod_wsgi, instead of just using the normal setup.

I understand that some people may feel that this question has no clear, opinion-free answer, but in fact it does.

Let me clarify with an example:

Positives for using Django with an Apache install include: 
Much easier transition from development server to production server
Developing using Apache will make programming server-based issues possible, instead of waiting to do such things on a production server

*end*

These are obviously objective benefits to using Django with Apache and if anybody can share their objective-based answers relating to why using an Apache-based Django development server, this will be much appreciated.

Also, there is no blog/question about this anywhere (or at least where I have looked).

Comment: Since 2008, I have yet to have a problem moving from the built-in server to production with Django. Of course, YMMV depeinding on what you're doing, but I don't see the need to set up an Apache/mod_wsgi environment for developing locally.

Comment: Setting up with Apache locally does help to test things such as the static files and other things within settings.py are ok. I quite often use both, have the dev on its port 8000, and a mod_wsgi locally. Every so often you can then bounce your local apache and check things without the effort of pushing somewhere remote

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I'll just go without Apache for now, although I do have it (but there's a PHP framework on my dev system too, so I don't want to cause conflicts).